# React-native: Adding colors to tailwind config isn't working as expected

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css

I am building an app with react-native (expo) and I use nativewind (tailwind for RN).

I've tried adding the colors as the documentations suggests, but it doesn't work as expected. I've tried everything I'll show below, and every time either the custom colors don't work or the base tailwind colors don't work.

These are the different configurations I've tried.

Config 1:

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        softBackground: "#f5f1eb",
        bubbleBackgroundCurrentUser: "#3b82f6",
        bubbleBackgroundOtherUser: "#3b82f6",
        bubbleTextColor: "#fff",
        bubbleTextColorChecked: "#d1d5db",
      },
    },
  },
```

Config 2:

```
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      softBackground: "#f5f1eb",
      bubbleBackgroundCurrentUser: "#3b82f6",
      bubbleBackgroundOtherUser: "#3b82f6",
      bubbleTextColor: "#fff",
      bubbleTextColorChecked: "#d1d5db",
    },
  },
```

And then I tried both, but by also dropping in the base tailwind colors as follows:

Config 3:

```
const tailwindcolors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
.
.
.
.
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        ...colors,
        softBackground: "#f5f1eb",
        bubbleBackgroundCurrentUser: "#3b82f6",
        bubbleBackgroundOtherUser: "#3b82f6",
        bubbleTextColor: "#fff",
        bubbleTextColorChecked: "#d1d5db",
      },
    },
  },
```

Config 4:

```
const tailwindcolors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
.
.
.
.
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      ...colors,
      softBackground: "#f5f1eb",
      bubbleBackgroundCurrentUser: "#3b82f6",
      bubbleBackgroundOtherUser: "#3b82f6",
      bubbleTextColor: "#fff",
      bubbleTextColorChecked: "#d1d5db",
    },
  },
```

Comment: Have you managed to make it worked?